# How to start with Ruby on Windows?

Tags: ruby

I have an homework to do on a language that we haven't seen in our program and I have to do a web application with Ruby, but I don't know how to start?

Do I have to install things on my computer?

Which IDE I have to use?

How to proceed too?

What is Rail?

Comment: Visit [the official site of Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) first. Then google 'Ruby on Rails'. If you wanna learn Ruby the hard way, you can use Wordpad and the command prompt instead of an IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **DO I HAVE TO INSTALL THINGS ON MY COMPUTER**

**YES**. Here is the link for the windows installer. http://rubyinstaller.org/ As far as versions, I don't think it will matter to much for your case. I would chose 2.2.2.

Second I would download notepad++ It is a simple but powerful text editing tool that support syntax highlighting for a ton of languages. https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.7.9.2.html I would choose the installer.

### **IDE**

Personally for Ruby I don't think an IDE is what your looking for. Typically I would recommend notepad++ on half of your screen and command line terminal on the other half. As you make changes you will re-run your ruby program in the terminal. For small projects this works great.

### **HOW TO PROCEED**

This is a great website to get you started. You don't have to install anything and you don't have to know any CLI. https://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/ruby I would suggest finishing the whole ruby guide on that website and then downloading notepad++ and ruby and then trying some of the exercises on the website on your own.

### **WHAT IS RAILS**

Simply put.. it is a framework. You don't really need to worry about it when first learning ruby. Give yourself a couple weeks with ruby and when you feel ready read this https://www.railstutorial.org/book. That should get you caught up with rails. Here is the rails download link http://rubyonrails.org/download/